# Email forwarding preserving subaddress

Tags: dns, email

Is it possible to set up email forwarding which preserves sub addresses (address tags)? So, e.g. reply+tag1234@example.com goes to myexampleuser+tag1234@gmail.com?

Note that tag1234 could change to anything in each received email.

Comment: Which MTA/SMTP server do you use?  It can be some with `sendmail` even if you want to rewrite envelope sender address before forwarding. Use serverfault to get more specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with native email server programs but you could write your own program to do it for you (which would be better suited for http://www.stackoverflow.com).

I would be remiss if I didn't also point out that doing it precisely the way you are asking could be a recipe for trouble as you are creating a system whereby someone could send an email to reply+anything@domain.com and it would spam the gmail servers by sending an email to myexampleyser+anything@gmail.com. This would technically be considered an open email forwarder which could find your server being blacklisted as a source of SPAM. A more suitable way to do it if you are wanting to forward this through to another email would be to embed tge tag in the subject line which is the way most customer relations management software as well as most helpdesk software works...

So an email is sent to reply@example.com with the subject "Some subject (crm:2987349823)" as a for instance, then you can simply forward the email using cpanel or whatever email server software you are using to anyone else you want as the tag code in the subject line remains the same even if by forwarding the email a "fw: " string is prepended to the subject line.